# Symfony3 : Add user_id field in sessions table to prevent concurrent connections

Tags: php, session, authentication, pdo, symfony

My goal is to only allow one session per user.

To do that I'm trying to detect if a session is still active for a specific user when someone is trying to connect.

The best solution I came up with is to add the user id to my sessions storage on database but I can't make it work.

I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634139) and adapt it for Symfony 3 but I keep having the following error and can't figure out why ?:

```
AuthorizationChecker cannot be converted to string
```

Here is my code :

## UserIdPdoSessionHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Utils;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class UserIdPdoSessionHandler extends PdoSessionHandler
{
    /**
     * @var \PDO PDO instance.
     */
    private $pdo;

    /**
     * @var array Database options.
     */
    private $dbOptions;

    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo, array $dbOptions = array(), AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->dbOptions = array_merge(
            array('db_user_id_col' => 'user_id'),
            $dbOptions
        );
        $this->$authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->$tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;

        parent::__construct($pdo, $dbOptions);
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        // get table/columns
        $dbTable   = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
        $dbDataCol = $this->dbOptions['db_data_col'];
        $dbIdCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];

        try {
            $sql = "SELECT $dbDataCol FROM $dbTable WHERE $dbIdCol = :id";

            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();
            // it is recommended to use fetchAll so that PDO can close the DB cursor
            // we anyway expect either no rows, or one row with one column. fetchColumn, seems to be buggy #4777
            $sessionRows = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            if (count($sessionRows) == 1) {
                return base64_decode($sessionRows[0][0]);
            }

            // session does not exist, create it
            $this->createNewSession($id);

            return '';
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: %s', $e->getMessage()), 0, $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        // get table/column
        $dbTable     = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
        $dbDataCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_data_col'];
        $dbIdCol     = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];
        $dbTimeCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_time_col'];
        $dbUserIdCol = $this->dbOptions['db_user_id_col'];

        //session data can contain non binary safe characters so we need to encode it
        $encoded = base64_encode($data);

        $userId = $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ?
            $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getId() :
            null
        ;

        try {
            $driver = $this->pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);

            if ('mysql' === $driver) {
                // MySQL would report $stmt->rowCount() = 0 on UPDATE when the data is left unchanged
                // it could result in calling createNewSession() whereas the session already exists in
                // the DB which would fail as the id is unique
                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
                    "INSERT INTO $dbTable ($dbIdCol, $dbDataCol, $dbTimeCol, $dbUserIdCol) VALUES (:id, :data, :time, :user_id) " .
                    "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $dbDataCol = VALUES($dbDataCol), $dbTimeCol = VALUES($dbTimeCol)"
                );
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':data', $encoded, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(':time', time(), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
            } elseif ('oci' === $driver) {
                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("MERGE INTO $dbTable USING DUAL ON($dbIdCol = :id) ".
                    "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ($dbIdCol, $dbDataCol, $dbTimeCol, $dbUserIdCol) VALUES (:id, :data, sysdate, :user_id) " .
                    "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET $dbDataCol = :data WHERE $dbIdCol = :id");

                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':data', $encoded, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
            } else {
                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE $dbTable SET $dbDataCol = :data, $dbTimeCol = :time WHERE $dbIdCol = :id");
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':data', $encoded, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(':time', time(), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();

                if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
                    // No session exists in the database to update. This happens when we have called
                    // session_regenerate_id()
                    $this->createNewSession($id, $data);
                }
            }
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('PDOException was thrown when trying to write the session data: %s', $e->getMessage()), 0, $e);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function createNewSession($id, $data = '')
    {
        // get table/column
        $dbTable     = $this->dbOptions['db_table'];
        $dbDataCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_data_col'];
        $dbIdCol     = $this->dbOptions['db_id_col'];
        $dbTimeCol   = $this->dbOptions['db_time_col'];
        $dbUserIdCol = $this->dbOptions['db_user_id_col'];

        $userId = $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ?
            $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getId() :
            null
        ;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $dbTable ($dbIdCol, $dbDataCol, $dbTimeCol, $dbUserIdCol) VALUES (:id, :data, :time, :user_id)";

        //session data can contain non binary safe characters so we need to encode it
        $encoded = base64_encode($data);
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':data', $encoded, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':time', time(), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        return true;
    }
}
```

## services.yml

```
pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
        dsn:      "mysql:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"

session.handler.pdo:
    class:     UserBundle\Utils\UserIdPdoSessionHandler
    public:    false
    arguments: [ "@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%", "@service_container" ]
```

My first idea was to add the last sessionId used by the user, and to check if it's alive but the id stored in the database is different from the one retrieved by

```
$request->getSession()->getId();
```

**Am I doing it right ? Can you think of a better way to achieve my final goal ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I forgot to remove the "save_path" from my sessions config. 
That is why the session ID saved in the DB was not the same as the one retrieved from the Request object.

So I just added a field "lastSessionId" in my User entity so now I can check if this session is still active.